# Construct a second order linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

I'm wondering if somebody can help me with this question.

> Construct a second-order linear differential equation that has this following general solution:

> $$x(t)=a(t^2-1)+be^{t^2+t}$$ for a,b two constant.

I tried to compute : $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}x(t)$ and $\frac{d}{dt}x(t)$ and after put it in this following equation:

$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}x(t)+ a_1(t)\frac{d}{dt}x(t) + a_2(t)x(t) = u(t)$$

And then find $a_1(t),a_2(t)$ and $u(t)$ such that is it true. Hence we obtain :

$$a(2+a_1(t)2t + a_2(t)(t^2-1))+b(2e^{t^2+t} + (2t +1)e^{t^2+t} + a_1(t)(2t+1)e^{t^2+t} + a_2(t)e^{t^2+t}) = u(t)$$ Since I don't want a particular equation but one which is true, I consider that the parenthesis of b is equal to zero, and so I found :

$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}x(t) - (2t + 1)\frac{d}{dt}x(t) -2 x(t) = -a(6t^2-2t-3).$$

But I think it's not true, because there is always our constant a.

Comment: Just check by replacing $x(t)$ and its derivatives in the final expression and look what happens. $a$ seems to be tied to the particular solution $a(t^2+1)$ and the other term $be^{t^2+t}$ to the solution of the homogeneous equation, so the presence of $a$ in the final equation is not that strange to me.

Answer (score 1):

Given two linearly independent solutions $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ there is always a corresponding homogenous differential equation
$$
W(\phi_1,\phi_2, x) = W(\phi_1,\phi_2) x'' - W'(\phi_1,\phi_2) x' + W(\phi_1',\phi_2') x =0,
$$
where $W$ denotes the [Wronski determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian). More information can be found in Section 3.5 on my book on [Ordinary Differential Equations](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Egerald/ftp/book-ode/).

Comment: I'm wondering how we find this equality ?

Comment: You write down the determinant on the left and do a Laplace expansion with respect to the last row. If $x$ is a linear combination of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$, then the determinant on the left clearly vanishes, so the two functions are solutions of this ODE.

Comment: I think you mean to express that $0=W(ϕ_1,ϕ_2,x)$ is the second order DE, and the right side is just the Laplace expansion of the determinant on the left.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. I added this to my answer.